# Benchmarking C++ on Microcontroller more efficiently

Tags: c++, embedded, microcontroller, benchmarking

I'm interested in benchmarking the execution speed of various ETL and STL library functions on the NXP LPC 804 microcontroller. Currently, I'm doing so by creating a C++ program for each and every function, and then measuring the results with an oscilloscope, which on another note tends to yield quite variable results.

I've looked into various benchmarking suites such as Nanobench and Google Benchmark, however none have worked. Does anyone know of a more efficient solution? As this is moreso a methodological inquiry than a programming question per se, I don't have any code to attach.

If there is a more suitable Stack Exchange channel for this then I will happily delete this post and repost it there. Thanks!

**Edit**: To add a bit more detail:

- By 'variable' results, I mean that when I continuously run one function within a while loop, the period duration the oscilloscope gives flickers back and forth between several different frequencies. I've noticed this is more frequent in the millisecond scale than the microsecond scale.
- This is the structure of an example function benchmark:

```cpp
int main() {
    while (true) {
        // set GPIO pin
        // execute some function
        // clear GPIO pin
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- Since this is a formal research evaluation, I was advised to either use a standard benchmarking suite or use an oscilloscope, rather than create benchmarking functions using timers myself, as I was told that microcontroller timers are somewhat imprecise.

Comment: do you want to just measure execution time or this benchmarking is supposed to do something with I/O?

Comment: @bartop I just want to measure execution time.

Comment: @RichardRobinson Whats the exact issue with the oscilloscope?
Do you want to repeat the measurement to get an average ? And the oscilloscope is just too much manual overhead ?

Comment: What do you mean by "variable results", do you get different measures for *the same instruction sequence*? How do you measure the execution times, by toggling a pin?

Comment: An oscilloscope is the King of benchmarking. No trashware suite comes remotely close. Your problem is most likely related to how you test. For example, if you grab an individual function and put it out of context, you might be blocking optimizations. Or maybe you are benchmarking non-optimized code. Etc.

Comment: And obviously if there are background interrupts running, they may affect the measurement drastically.

Comment: The question may be "why is oscilloscope giving variable results ?" Indeed results should be reproductible. If you want a method with less external material and overhead you may use Cortex cycle counter to measure execution time. If measurement are not reproductible you may post some code to investigate about the cause of the variations.

Comment: does it vary per build and consistent within a build?  many reasons why execution time will vary including when you re-build where the function under tests lands and optimization and other factors can change its execution time.  also how are you getting a signal to the scope to see this and whatever that call is can vary, just like making time measurements from timer functions the timer functions can make the test vary as well as the code under test.

Comment: as soon as you think you have timed the functions and pick a path for the application then those timings can/will change.

Comment: @Nextar There are several problems, the main one being is that I want to test ~200 functions / variations thereof and so far my workflow has been to make a source program for each function, and then manually run and measure each one, which is very inefficient and very manual. See my edit for more details.

Comment: @thebusybee I mean when I continuously run the function and toggle a GPIO pin, the period the oscilliscope measures flickers back and forth between various values. See my edit for more details.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC804.pdf) the LPC804 has a "32-bit general purpose counter/timer", maybe you could configure it to make the measurement. This way you could write timing code once and check the results programmatically.